# how to use media player in dialog alert button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-alertdialog

I try to play media player in dialog alert button, somehow it doesn't work but there is no error notification, the dialog works perfectly, and the cancel button the, but for the media player doesn't work

```
    public void TampilanDoa() {
        tampilan = new Dialog(DoaHarianActivity.this);
        tampilan.setContentView(R.layout.layout_doa);

        dengar = tampilan.findViewById(R.id.btdengar);
        kembali = tampilan.findViewById(R.id.btkembali);

        final MediaPlayer

        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splash);

        dengar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        kembali.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tampilan.cancel();
            }
        });

        tampilan.show();
    }
}
```